# Regular Expression Help for grok

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regular expression for [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok), unfortunately it's not working for me

```
 2015-02-26 12:38:04 -0800 (Thu, 26 Feb 2015)
```

I wrote this but it's not working

```
 (?>\d\d){1,2}-(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9]) (?:2[0123]|[01]?[0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:(?:[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?) (?:Z|[+-]%{HOUR}(?::?%{MINUTE}))  ((?:Mon(?:day)?|Tue(?:sday)?|Wed(?:nesday)?|Thu(?:rsday)?|Fri(?:day)?|Sat(?:urday)?|Sun(?:day)?), (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9]) \b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b (?>\d\d){1,2})
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: don't parse dates with regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Unfortunately I don't have that option,I am using logstash and to filter logs I must need to specify regex to parse those logs

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure it out

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\ -[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\ \([A-Z][a-z][a-z]\,\ [0-9][0-9]\ [A-Z][a-z][a-z]\ [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)"
```